# Google Earth Pro on 18.01.1 not opening GPX files

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, google-earth, xml, gps

I'm having a problem where Google Earth Pro is unable to open a GPX file, i.e. a file from my GPS unit.  It can open KML/KMZ files without issue.  I'm running the latest updates on 18.01.1 and the latest Google Earth Pro at 7.3.0.3832 (64-bit).  Why am I posting this here?  Because I think it's a problem with something since 17.10.  I have no problem opening a GPX file on my Mac (test point 1).  I have no problem opening a GPX file in a virtual 16.04.4 (test point 2).  I'm not able to open a GPX file on multiple 18.01.1 machines.

There are no errors and no messages if I start from the command line.  It's like it's not even recognizing the file at all, i.e. no movement to focus on the GPS track.

A GPX file is XML.  Has there been a change to a library that Google Earth is using that might be causing this annoyance?  How can I diagnose or debug this problem?

Comment: I did check to see if there were an update and yes, there's was, i.e. 7.3.2.5491 (64-bit).  Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.  In general, you call the script `/opt/google/earth/pro/googleearth`, which sets up library paths.  By calling just the ELF, `googleearth-bin`, opens the GPX without issue.

I'm not sure if it's solved, but it's solved to my satisfaction.

Comment: When I posted this to Google's forums, they asked for ldd info.  Hopefully this gets resolved on their end.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as OP in 18.04, and although it's been almost a year, I thought including it here would be useful for future viewers.

Do you have GPSBabel, or anything that depends on it (such as GPS Prune) installed?
This issue could be caused by a conflict between Google Earth's version of GPSBabel and the other one installed on your system.  For me, uninstalling GPS Prune immediately fixed the issue.

Inspired by Gyula Zilahi's post at https://support.google.com/earth/thread/4752997?hl=en.